# PHP Script to retrieve filename as an achor tag

Tags: php, file, dir, readdir, opendir

I can't work out how to write a PHP script that will iterate over a set of files in a folder (let's say, 3 MP3 files), output the filename and add anchor tags around this to provide a download link.

I assume this is how I would begin but I have no idea where to go.

```
$dir = opendir("Z:\\uploads\\");  
while ($name = readdir($dir)) {
```

Comment: No idea? Does that mean you don't know how to output anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir= opendir("Z:\\uploads\\"); 
echo '<ul>';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($fn = readdir($handle))) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.realpath($dir.$fn).'">'. basename($fn).' </a></li>';
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: and where have you intialized `$thisdir`  ?

Comment: Typo thanks. That's why you would comment not downvote.

Comment: Removed it . Its fine now.

Comment: @popnoodles where are you initializing $dir? - apologies if this is a silly question

Comment: @user3499345 there was a(nother) typo. Check now.